# Is there affordable hardware to scan plastic models and reveal their internal structure?

Tags: scanner

I know, there are medical scanners which can do that with ultrasound, but this equipment if awfully expensive. I’m looking for something much cheaper, say, under $500 and it does not have to be off-the-shelve. I'm equally interested in components which can be used to build it.

Let's consider a specific example. I have an empty plastic bottle with a pump (e.g. for liquid soap). I would like to scan it with a step of 1/8'' and get an image of a bottle reveling the internal structure of the bottle at each step. At the first step I will see only the outline of the bottle walls, but as I progress deeper I should be able to see the pump and the straw inside. Something like XRay for plastic with configurable depth of readings.

Comment: Realistically a practical need would be solved by disassembling the pump from the bottle and carefully measuring the components, cutting it into pieces if necessary.  The bottle you might scan, externally but is also less critical.

Comment: Well, the bottle is just an example. I'm thinking of scanning plastic objects of any kind. Sometimes the internal structure can be quite complex.

Comment: Things like desktop 3D printers get us closer to a Star Trek universe where complexity is just arbitrary data, but the reality is that such approaches tend to be expensive and yield poorer results than techniques specifically tuned to an application.  Where suitable quality can be obtained at an acceptable price direct-to-data methods are a convenience... where it can't, you can either sit around waiting for magic or get yourself a cheap pair of digital calipers.